# Gaussian fit to estimate parameters in R

Tags: r, gaussian, data-fitting

I have a dataframe `df` with columns x,y and z, where z are measurements of a parameter along x and y coordinates. I want to fit this to Gaussian surface of equation;
z(x,y)=a0*exp{­-ax*(x­-x0)^2­-ay*(y-y0)^2}

To find a0 as the height of Gaussian, ax and ay are Gaussian width parameters, x0 and y0 are central location of Gaussian.

I have tried `optim` but it does not work. I do not have a strong background in stats, so please excuse if the question is too basic.

Comment: I have tried `nls`, which gives result but the mean y it gives has value more than maximum of y... which means the mean point will lie outside the study area.. any kind of help would be appreciated!